# How to manage multiple environments for an app on Ubuntu with Apache server?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, linode, ubuntu-22.04

I have a PHP app and I would like to host staging, demo, and production servers from one instance on Linode. The challenge I am running into is loading different environment variables for each server.

I have created multiple .conf files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ which look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin info@example.com
     ServerName stag.example.com
     ServerAlias stag.example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/example-app/public
     ErrorLog /var/www/example-app/writable/logs/errors.stag.log
     CustomLog /var/www/example-app/writable/logs/access.stag.log combined
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =stag.example.com
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried creating .sh files for each server in the /etc/profile.d/ directory that include all the environment variables, which look like this:

```
export ENV1="abc"
export ENV2="def"
```

But I don't know how I can load that file in the .conf file. I have also tried explicitly setting an APP_ENV variable in the .conf (i.e. `SetEnv APP_ENV staging`). I would then check the APP_ENV variable in the PHP code (i.e. `getenv("APP_ENV")`) and based on that, I could then read the correct .sh file and load the environment variables in that file into $_ENV. However, for some reason, the APP_ENV variable is not showing up when I retrieve all the environment variables in my PHP code (i.e. `print_r getenv()`). When I do that, only the variables set in the /etc/apache2/envvars are listed.

I am new to Ubuntu and Linode (previously, I only used managed servers), so it is possible I am missing something simple, so any help you can provide, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

PHP environnement variables are not the same as your system ones or apache ones.

If you want to set an APP_ENV environment variable that could be retrieved from your PHP code using `getenv("APP_ENV")`, you shall consider declaring it in your `php.ini` file. (better explanation here: https://w3schools.in/php/environment-variables )

1. Go to `/etc/php/XX/apache2/php.ini` (where XX depends of your PHP version)
2. Add a variable (example: `APP_ENV = "PROD"`)
3. Read it from your PHP code `getenv("APP_ENV"`)

Does it helps?
Best regards.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why the system environment variables weren't accessible to the PHP code. Is there a preferred way to determine which server is being loaded (e.g. staging or production), so the APP_ENV variable can be set correctly?

Comment: If i understand well what you want to do. Inside your apache <VirtualHost *:80> directive, you may add a "SetEnv APP_ENV XXXX" (where XXXX is what you want).
Like that, your PHP will be able to retrieve the APP_ENV variable modified corresponding to your virtual_host. This is something that you may also specify in servers .htaccess files.

Comment: Yes, that is what I assumed, but when I then try to retrieve that variable in my PHP code, I don't see any results. I've tried each of these in my PHP code: `print_r($_ENV);` `print_r($_SERVER);` `echo apache_getenv("APP_ENV");` `echo $_SERVER["APP_ENV"];` and `echo getenv("APP_ENV");`

Comment: Okay i see. In your `php-fpm.conf` file, try to find the directive `clear_env` and set it to 'no'. `clear_env = no`. Then restart php-fpm, and restart apache2. And try again displaying the variable.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help here. Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. For reference, this is what I did. 1. `apt-get install php-fpm`
2. `nano /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
3. uncommented `clear_env = no`
4. `systemctl start php8.1-fpm.service`
5. `systemctl reload apache2`

Comment: Just a question: may you confirm which php configuration file is linked to your apache2 server? Its in your apache.conf file.

Comment: In my phpinfo.php page, it shows the php configuration file as  /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini. I don't see a apache.conf file, but I do see a apache2.conf in the /etc/apache2 directory. That file doesn't seem to refer to any php config file though.

Comment: Just to follow-up on this, I believe the variables set with SetEnv were not available in the PHP code because I did not have the mod_php module enabled (h/t to https://www.linode.com/community/questions/23444/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-set-in-conf-file-in-php-code). Rather than enable that, which would have conflicted with multi-threaded modules that I have installed, I instead relied on the host to determine which environment to load, then pretty much followed your directions. Thanks again for the assistance.